# How to create a sorted list or dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I want to create a list of string, and the elements are ordered by string length. For example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx']
```

While I insert an element into this initial empty my_list, how to maintain such an order? In Java, I can create a custom order function and pass that as a constructor parameter.

I just found that this is the simplest way:

```
l = sorted(my_list, key=str.__len__)
```

Comment: You can use [`sortedcontainers.SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is using `bisect.insort` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort)). This function will insert value into list while maintaining sorted order:

```
from collections import UserString
from bisect import insort

class custom_string(UserString):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self) == len(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return len(self) < len(other)


def insert(lst, s):
    insort(my_list, custom_string(s))

my_list = []

insert(my_list, 'cde')
insert(my_list, 'a')
insert(my_list, 'bc')
insert(my_list, 'xxxx')
insert(my_list, 'fef')

print(my_list)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'bc', 'cde', 'fef', 'xxxx']
```

EDIT: The values in the `my_list` are of type `custom_string` with custom `__eq__` and `__lt__` functions. To retype it back to normal string use for example `str()`.

Comment: While this works, it's worst-time-complexity is bad (because while bisect finds the place to insert the strings in logarithmic time, inserting them is linear). May or may not be a problem for OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list with the `heapq` module to keep it "sorted"*.

```
import heapq

my_list = []
for value in ['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx']:
    heapq.heappush(my_list, value)
```

To supply a custom sort function, you can use a small wrapper:

```
class Heap(list):
    """
    A lightweight heap essentially utilizing the heapq module.
    It can however be supplied a key argument on initialization. The heap
    itself is a list of tuples of (key, element), but popping is transparent.
    """

    def __init__(self, initial=None, key=lambda x: x):
        """
        Return an empty heap.
        If it has the argument 'initial', it is assumed to be an iterable from
        which the heap will be initialized.
        'key' is a function similar to those usable in the sort() function,
        which will be used whenever a comparison is made.
        """
        self.key = key
        if initial:
            self.extend((key(item), item) for item in initial)
            heapq.heapify(self)

    def push(self, item):
        """Push an element on the heap."""
        heapq.heappush(self, (self.key(item), item))

    def pop(self):
        """Pop the smallest element off the heap, maintaining the invariant."""
        return heapq.heappop(self)[1]

    def replace(self, item):
        """
        Pop an element off the heap, then push.
        More efficient then first popping and then pushing.
        """
        return heapq.heapreplace(self, (self.key(item), item))[1]

    def pushpop(self, item):
        """
        Push an element on the heap, then pop and return the smallest item.
        More efficient then first pushing and then popping.
        """
        return heapq.heappushpop(self, (self.key(item), item))[1]
```

Usage:

```
>>> my_heap = Heap(['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx'])
>>> my_heap.push('fooooo')
```

---

*: The list behind the heap will not look sorted, but when using the heap interface it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SortedList like this. You might have to install it sortedcontainer first to use it

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
x=['fef', 'cde', 'xxxx','a', 'bc']
sl = SortedList(x,key=lambda x: len(x))
list(sl) #['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply sort it as you said in your post. However, if you want to insert a new incoming element at an appropriate index (by appropriate meaning, the insert should not disturb the increasing 'length' criteria) then below is also a simple function. I have assumed that you already have a list my_list = ['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx'] and then you want to insert new strings from Random_Strings = ['b','ghij','fgh'].

```py
import numpy as np
my_list = ['a', 'bc', 'fef', 'cde', 'xxxx']
Random_Strings = ['b','ghij','fgh']

def add_string_at_appropriate_index(ListWhereToInsert,StringToInsert):
    Diff_of_Length = np.array([len(x)-len(StringToInsert) for x in ListWhereToInsert])
    AppropriateIndex = np.where(Diff_of_Length==0)[0][0]
    ListWhereToInsert.insert(AppropriateIndex,StringToInsert)
    return ListWhereToInsert

for each_random_string in Random_Strings:
    my_list = add_string_at_appropriate_index(my_list,each_random_string)

print(my_list)
```

When I run it I get an already sorted list after each insertion. No need to sort after every insertion. The output of the print is as below.

```sh
['b', 'a', 'bc', 'fgh', 'fef', 'cde', 'ghij', 'xxxx']
```

Just another way to do the same job (as has already been provided in this thread). May be useful to somebody in a particular situation. In this case you have already found a solution, so congrats!